# No EFI partition found... Please go back and add an EFI system partition

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, grub-efi, nvme

I'm looking for help with the error message: `No EFI partition found... Please go back and add an EFI system partition..`

I had installed Ubuntu 19.10 as a dual boot with an existing Windows 10 HP Spectre 13T laptop. It worked fine for a day and then I could no longer find it as a boot menu selection. I can only get into Windows 10. After doing lots of reading, I think it's because I hadn't deactivated the sleep/hibernation in Windows, and had closed the lid and activated it, causing some kind of EFI corruption. After then is when the issue started. I've now deactivated that function in Windows, but it's too late.

When I tried just doing a live USB (created with Rufus) erase and reinstall it got almost to the end and then complained:

```
Executing grub-install/dev/mvneOn1 failed. This is a fatal error.
```

Now when I try doing a reinstall without erasing, Ubuntu says:

```
No EFI System Partition was found. 
The system will likely not be able to boot successfully, and the installation
process may fail. Please go back and add an EFI Partition,
or continue at your own risk."
```

The problem is that I *do* have such a partition. I've attached here what it looks like:

[image: EaseUS Partition Master]

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer that worked for me and solved the problem entirely!

"Get boot-repair and use that from usb 
help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
"